# Why is my module not working? Trying to modify the $block element on success page

Tags: magento2

I have written a module that should extend the `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Success`-Block. My modules structure is the following:

```
Vendor
- Namepsace
- - Block
- - - Checkout
- - - - Success.php
- - etc 
- - - frontend
- - - - di.xml
- - - module.xml 
- - registration.php
- - composer.json
```

Success.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Success
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSuccessTrackingCode()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($this->getLastOrderId());
        $orderID = $order->getOrderID();
        $total = $order->getGrandTotal();
        $shipping = $order->getShippingAmount();
        $tax = $order->getTaxAmount();
        //$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $storeName = "Shopname";

        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        $item_details = array() ;

        foreach($items as $item):
            $det = array() ;
            $det['sku'] = $item->getSku();
            $det['name'] = $item->getName();
            $det['price'] =  number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2, ',', '.') . "€";
            $det['quantity'] = number_format($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0);
            $det['id'] = $item->getID();
            array_push($item_details, $det);
        endforeach;

        $html = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        $html .= "ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');"
        $html .= "ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {";
        $html .= "'id': '" . $orderID . "',";
        $html .= "'affiliation': '" . $storeName . "',"
        $html .= "'revenue': '" . $order->getGrandTotal . "',";
        $html .= "'shipping': '" . $shipping . "',"
        $html .= "'tax': '" . $tax . "'";
        $html .= "});";

        // ITEMS 


        foreach($item_details as $item):

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item['id']);
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
            if(count($cats) ){
               $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
               $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($firstCategoryId);
                  $catName = $_category->getName();
            }

            $html .= "ga('ecommerce:addItem', {";
            $html .= "'id': '" . $orderID . "',";
            $html .= "'name': '" . $item['name']. "',";
            $html .= "'sku': '" . $item['sku'] . "',";
            $html .= "'category': '" . $catName . "', ";
            $html .= "'price': '" . $item['price'] . "', ";
            $html .= "'quantity': '" . $item['quantity'] . "'";
            $html .= "});"

        endforeach;

        $html .= "ga('ecommerce:send');";
        $html .= "</script>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Success"
                type="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Checkout\Success"/>
</config>
```

in the `success.phtml` I'm now trying to get the aboves $html via

```
$block->getSuccessTrackingCode();
```

But its empty, theres no return of $html.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the following in your template `echo get_class($block);` and see what it outputs

Comment: Will try to do so, Raphael. Just give me some minutes.

Comment: It outputs " Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success " and thats it.

Comment: It should output `Vendor\Namespace\Block\Checkout\Success` . Double check if module is enabled, clear caches and var/di folder.

Comment: Did both. Even did setup:di:compile just to be sure, no changes on success.phtml.

Comment: have you checked function is called or not? inside getSuccessTrackingCode() and getting orderid?

Comment: You mean, just echoing something inside the function? Correct me if I'm wrong, but if a echo works, $block->getSuccessTrackingCode() shouldn't trigger true on a !empty if-check.

Comment: Yes you're right, the test you made by checking the class of the block shows that the preference is not working so your function cannot be called. I suggest you check you haven't made a typo in the folder names / class names

Comment: Can confirm that there is no typo. Crosschecked everything before creating this threat, but thanks for that tip - such mistakes happens all the time! :-)

Comment: Any new ideas on this?

Comment: Is your module listed in the `setup_module` table of your database ?

Comment: Yes, it has been correctly registered, right after I fired setup:upgrade. I checked that also before.

Comment: @Atr_Max Which is your Magento version?

Comment: can you try `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Success` note the extra slash in the beginning to tell Magento to look it from root.

Comment: I am using Magento 2.0.4. - there is already an extra slash in my version, see the unedited code above.

Comment: Any updates on this? Still struggeling!

Comment: Did you find a solution? having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunetly not. :/ Management hasn't provided more time for that issue but I will keep an eye on it, as soon as I have the solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: If It outputs `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success` why do you extend `Magento\Checkout\Block\Success`

Answer (score 0):

My current guess is that your extension's `etc\module.xml` file does not include a sequence node for Magento_Checkout. This in turn can mean that your extension is loaded before the original Magento module, hence your preference is not loaded last.

To confirm you could take a look at `app/etc/config.php` to view the current load order. Your extension should come after Magento_Checkout.